# limit points of $[0,1]$

Tags: general-topology

$[0,1]$ defined in $\mathbb{R}$ is a closed set. A closed set contains all its limit points. The points $0$ and $1$ do not have all their neighbourhoods within $[0,1]$.

So they are not limit points ? But $0$ is a limit point of set 1/n which should be a subset of $[0,1]$ ?

Definition of limit point: A real number x is a limit point of a set S if every neighborhood of x contains an infinite number of elements of S.

Wikipedia definition: A point x in X is a limit point of S if every neighbourhood of x contains at least one point of S different from x itself. This suggests $0$ is a limit. So, the first definition is wrong ??

Then what are the limit points of $[0,1]$ ?

How do we "find" limit points of "simple sets"(if there is such a thing) like $[0,1]$?

I am aware of the fact that openness, closedness are not mutually exclusive. I am struggling with visualising the concept of closure of set.

Comment: What is your definition of a limit point?

Comment: Definition of limit point: A real number x is a limit point of a set S if every neighborhood of x contains an infinite number of elements of S.

Comment: Does a neighborhood of $0$ in $[0,1]$ contain infinitely elements of $[0,1]$? Note the definition does not say the neighborhood needs to be a subset of $S$.

Comment: not all neighborhoods of $0$ ..

Comment: What is a neighborhood not containing infinitely many points of $[0,1]$?

Comment: $0-e$ is not in $[0,1]$

Comment: That is a number less than zero, not a neighborhood of $0$. Neighborhoods are open sets.

Comment: ok .. so that means I don't understand neighborhoods .. what am I supposed to do now ?

Comment: ohh ok .. I think I got what you were trying to say ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**
In $\mathbb R$, all neighborhoods of a point $x$ contain a neighborhood of the form $B_\epsilon(x) = (x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)$. Thus a point is a limit point of $S$ iff
$(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon) \cap S$ contains infinitely many points for all $\epsilon > 0$. Now note that for $\epsilon < 1$
$$(-\epsilon, \epsilon) \cap [0,1] = [0, \epsilon)$$
wich contains infinitely many points and for $\epsilon \ge 1$, $(-\epsilon, \epsilon) \cap [0,1] = [0,1]$ wich contains infinitely many points so $0$ is indeed a limit point of $[0,1]$.
Proceed in the same way with $1$.

Comment: half an hour of head banging .. hopefully learnt something .. Thanks

Comment: @square_one Always happy to help. If anything remained unclear, feel free to ask for clarification :)

Comment: is there any "Topology for Dummies" book ?

Comment: @square_one This (topology of $\mathbb R^n$) should be covered in any reasonably good Calculus II book. If you're German you may want to take a look at _O. Forster, Analysis II_