# Why $0.5$ is not a limit point of $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am trying to understand, for every $r>0$ we have $B(0.5,r)\cap [0,1]\neq \emptyset$ so shouldnt $0.5$ be a limit point of $[0,1]$?

Comment: $\frac12$ *is* a limit point of $[0,1]$. Who told you that it wasn’t?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I read http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1057292/limit-points-of-0-1 ,So I got it wrong, so in fact every number in $[0,1]$ is a limit point of $[0,1]$?
Does the theorem about a closed set$\iff$ all of its limit point contained in the set promise that every element of the set is a limit point?

Comment: No, it doesn’t: it’s strictly one-way. Every limit point of the set is in the set, but the set may contain points that are not limit points of it. An example is the set $[0,1]\cup\{2\}$: $2$ is in the set, but it’s not a limit point of the set. Another example is the two-point set $\{0,1\}$: it’s vacuously true that it contains all of it’s limit points, since it has no limit points that aren’t in it, because it has no limit points in the first place!

Comment: @gbox When a set is closed and every point of the set is a limit point, the set is called "perfect". So yes, the closed interval is perfect. But It does not have to be that every closed set is perfect.  For example, the singleton set $\{1\}$ is closed, but 1 is not a limit point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We say that $x$ is a limit point of $A$ if any neighborhood of $x$ intersects the set $A$ in at least one point other than $x$.

In metric spaces every neighborhood of a point $x$ contains some open ball $\Bbb B(x,\epsilon)$. Then $x$ is a limit point of $A$ if for every $\epsilon>0$ we have that

$$A\cap(\Bbb B(x,\epsilon)\setminus\{x\})\neq\emptyset$$

Then we have that any interior point of $A$ is also a limit point of $A$, which is the case for $1/2$ in the interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: Why we require $$A\cap(\Bbb B(x,\epsilon)\setminus\{x\})\neq\emptyset$$
does not $$A\cap(\Bbb B(x,\epsilon))\neq\emptyset$$ sufficient (in $\mathbb{R^n})$?

Comment: Because it is defined in this manner. The definition is a way to translate the concept of functional limit on topology. Notice that the functional limit as we write $\lim_{x\to y}f(x)=L$ is defined as $$\forall \epsilon>0,\exists\delta>0: 0<|x-y|<\delta\implies |f(x)-L|<\epsilon$$ Then the part "$0<$" means that $x$ is excluded.

Comment: I had a mistake in my last comment: it is $y$ what is excluded in the above definition of functional limit.

Answer (score 1):

With

$$a_n=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n},$$

we have

$$\forall \epsilon>0 \;\;\exists N=\lfloor \frac{1}{\epsilon } \rfloor +1\;:\:$$

$$\frac{1}{2}-\epsilon<a_N<\frac{1}{2}$$

thus, $\frac{1}{2}$ is limit of a non stationnary sequence of elements in $[0,1]$, which means that $\frac{1}{2}$ is a limit point of $[0,1]$.